# Calculating multiple quaternions between 2 quaternions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I have a problem with calculating multiple quaternions between 2 quaternions.

Example on the image: 
[image]

Q1 has localEulerAngles.y at 7

Q4 has localEulerAngles.y at -17.4

I can get center quaternion between Q1 and Q4 for example by:
`Quaternion.Slerp(Q1.transform.localRotation, Q4.transform.localRotation, 0.5f);`

And it gives me "-5.2" value - which is great if I want only one quaternion in between Q1 and Q4.

But what if I want more quaternions?

Slerp of Q1,"-5.2" and Q4,"-5.2" is not it - they are off center a little if you think about it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use different values for `t`:

```
int numberOfBetweenQuaternions = 2;
Quaternion[] inBetweenQuaternions = new Quaternion[numberOfBetweenQuaternions];

for (int i = 0 ; i < numberOfBetweenQuaternions ; i++) 
{
    inBetweenQuaternions[i] = Quaternion.Slerp(
            Q1.transform.localRotation, 
            Q4.transform.localRotation, 
            (i+1f)/(numberOfBetweenQuaternions+1f));
}

Q2.transform.localRotation = inBetweenQuaternions[0];
Q3.transform.localRotation = inBetweenQuaternions[1];
```

Comment: Ouuuu... didn't think of just changing t parameter... simple.
Turned out it still didn't solve my problem completely but a bit of progress is made :) Thanks!